# Copy in FOR loop works but keeps giving the error "The file cannot be copied onto itself"

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, copy

So when I copy using the dirs `%userprofile%\Desktop\Out` and  `%userprofile%\Desktop\Out\test` The `.txt` are copied over however I get the error `The file cannot be copied onto itself.`

When I run the script with `%userprofile%\Desktop\Out` and `%userprofile%\Desktop\New Folder` It runs smoothly.

So my question is why does the script get confused when you copy from a common root folder to a different sub folder?

```
@ECHO ON
FOR /r "%userprofile%\Desktop\Out" %%a IN (*.txt) DO copy "%%a" "%userprofile%\Desktop\New Folder"
pause
```

Comment: This happens when there are already `*.txt` files in `%userprofile%\Desktop\Out\test`, which are enumerated by `for /R "%userprofile%\Desktop\Out"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination directory `%userprofile%\Desktop\Out\test` is a subdirectory of the source, whereas `%userprofile%\Desktop\New Folder` is not.

Since you are using `for /r`, the copied files would be copied from the lower directory as the recursion takes place - FROM the destination directory INTO the destination directory. Hence, a file would be copied over itself.