# Xcopy to multiple folder into subdirectory

Tags: windows, batch-file

**Xcopy to multiple folder with the same name into multiple subdirectory**

E:\copytest\aaaa\2

E:\copytest\bbbb\2

E:\copytest\randome\2

```
xcopy  E:\copytest\new.txt E:\copytest\%%\2
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571781/copy-in-for-loop-works-but-keeps-giving-the-error-the-file-cannot-be-copied-ont

Comment: @Jonas i don't know the director name before main director that is why i want to use %%

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this

```
@ECHO OFF
xcopy "E:\copytest\new.txt" "E:\copytest\aaaa\2" /z /i
xcopy "E:\copytest\new.txt" "E:\copytest\bbbb\2" /z /i
xcopy "E:\copytest\new.txt" "E:\copytest\randome\2" /z /i
PAUSE
```

Check out [this](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) and [this](https://www.windows-commandline.com/xcopy-command-syntax-examples/) link also remember you can make it easier with a for loop.

Try create a variable for `E:\copytest\new.txt` if you want to shorten the code.

Comment: hello there are many random directory under sub folder that is why i want use %%

Comment: @jhon de You will have to search through those directory's and find the common folder `2` and copy `new.txt` to folder `2` in all those directory's. Is that right?